# Word To Excel using .net c#

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

How to convert data from MS word doc to MS Excel using  .net, actually word doc having some data like rows and columns with out using table. I want to convert that into Excel sheet using .NET. Please help me on this..

Comment: That depends very much on the formats you use, but basically I'd try to parse the word file's text like a csv file, and then import that to excel (which natively supports csv), maybe "faking" a file with a stream. Also, look at `Microsoft.Interop.Word` and `Microsoft.Interop.Excel`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid that having worked with the MS Word object model in the past, unless the data is in structure that can be relied upon, such as a table, you will really struggle to focus on consistent and reliable delimiters for splitting the data into rows and cloumns.

Any minor difference in different documents will have a bewildering array of effect on your ability to hone in on any such delimiters.  You may get something working in a document or 10, but you will likely come across documents in the future that break the functionality acheived initially.

I know it's not much help, but this one will frustrate the hell out of you long term if you pursue it.  My apologies for my take on this one - sorry!